# Loop through each element and add values to a new object. Add these objects to array & access their values

Tags: javascript

I have an element called `lineNumber` that contains some form inputs. All the values of the inputs are stored in variables.

```
<div class="lineNumber">    
        <div class="input-container">
            <label>Example Line 1 :</label>
            <input type="text" name="lineText" value="John's Electrical" class="lineText">
        </div>
        <!-- more inputs... -->
    </div>
```

On page load there is one instance of this element.I add new instances of `lineNumber` dynamically with a button.

At this stage I have retrieved all the values of the first instance and placed in variables that update onchange. The challenge is iterating for each new instance.

I would like to loop through each instance of `lineNumber` and store the values of each variable in an object. I would also like the object values to be updated when the variables are as well.

I have eventListeners that detect a change to the input and update the value of the variable.

```
//wrap this in lineNumber.length loop?
let lineText = lineNumber[i].querySelector('.lineText');
let lineTextValue = lineNumber[i].querySelector('input[name="lineText"]').value;
//end of loop?

//add event listener and update lineTextValue
lineText.addEventListener("keyup", liveTextFunction);

//store value in variable lineTextValue;
function liveTextFunction(){
    lineTextValue = lineNumber[i].querySelector('input[name="lineText"]').value;    
}

//createLineObject() runs when new lineNumber element added
//store values *** //
let lineObject;
function createLineObject(){
    lineObject = { };
    lineObject[lineNumber] = lineNumberValue;
    lineObject[lineText] = lineTextValue;
};
```

Hoping to end up with multiple lineObjects that I can access the values from eg

`lineObject[1].lineNumberValue` or `Object.entries(lineObject[1]);`

Not sure if the objects would then go in an array? eg

```
objectArray[ lineObject[1], lineObject[2] ];
```

Hoping for some guidance on how to achieve this or constructive criticism on my approach. I'm just not sure if I'm approaching this the right way and could use some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Is every `<input/>` you're trying to query going to have the `name="linetext"`? If so, you could iterate through your `"lineNumber"` divs and iterate through the `"linetext"` inputs below them with something like this:

```
lineObjects = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.lineNumber')).map(div => {
  return Array.from(div.querySelectorAll('input[name="linetext"]')).map(input => {
    // do whatever you need to do with each div and input
    const lineObject = {
      div: div,
      input: input,
      value: null,  // set automatically by listener
      removeListener: null  // call when lineObject no longer needed
    };
    const listener = event => {
      lineObject.value = event.target.value;
    }
    input.addEventListener('keyup', listener);
    lineObject.removeListener = () => input.removeEventListener('keyup', listener);
    return lineObject;
  });
});
lineObjects = lineObjects.flat(); // convert array of arrays to flat array
```

As an aside, this is already pretty unwieldy and it is for a single piece of functionality. You'd also have to run this again on adding new `lineNumber`s after cleaning up the listeners on the existing `lineObjects`. I'd suggest using a framework like React if possible.

Comment: Thanks. Each input is unique but I already have the value of each stored in a variable. Only one lineText per LineNumber. Using vanilla js only as a learning experience. If I have all the values in variables cant I just add them to an object as a key:value pair like my example?

Comment: It sounds like you want two-way binding, where the JS object changes in response to the DOM element, and vice versa. You can pretty easily get all the values you want at a given time. However, you need to manage event listeners to get the changes, or the values in your variables will go stale. Handling dynamically added and deleted DOM elements is also tricky.

Comment: Your right and I actually have a handle on all the issues you mentioned. I think I'm overthinking the part I'm struggling with as it sounds like it shouldn't be that complicated. If I run createLineObject() for each new line  I just need to add the values to the object when I loop over lineNumber. Appreciate this is not much info to go on. At least I can look into some docs on two way binding did not know the term for that.